# "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context" but code IS in object context

Tags: php, oop

I'm getting the old familiar "Fatal error: Using $this when not in object context" referring to `$this->test = 'test';` in the following class:

```
class Example {
    public $test;
    public function index() {
        $this->test = 'test';
    }
}
```

The class method is called via `call_user_func_array(array('example', 'index'), $params);`. I can only assume that `call_user_func_array` has for some reason decided to call the index method as static e.g. `example::index()`? However I haven't figured out a fix for this and oddly I've not had a problem with it until recently.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This works:

```
$obj = new Example();
call_user_func_array(array($obj, 'index'), $params);
```

Your code basically does:

```
Example::index($params);
```

which calls `index` statically, which you correctly assumed.

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm making use of autoloading sorry. I was under the impression that call_user_func_array would would without having to instantiate the class manually. Is this not the case?

Comment: @Riddian Nope. It's not. There would be no way to actually perform static calls. BTW: this behavior goes for all PHP functions taking callbacks (like [`usort`](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/function.usort.php) and the likes). See [Pseudo-types and variables...](http://de2.php.net/manual/en/language.pseudo-types.php#language.types.callback).